# MVC 4 intranet application authorization mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I'm writing an intranet application using MVC4 and designed as SPA application.
The application assumptions are that there is no SSO and the users will be stored at the SQL DB. 

I'm not interested in open authorization with external accounts. (As demonstrated in the SPA template). 
The users will have some custom fields (Mobile, Email etc.) 
Most of the actions are limited to certain roles.
I'm looking for the most built-in mechanims the achieve it.
I want to use the AutorizeFilter and avoid any custom implmenetations if possible. 
Mention that some of the actions are WebAPI in REST Services in the application. 
I didn't find a good "end to end" article that demonstrates how to implement and manage users and roles. 
Is there a template that comes with login views, models etc. and is there supporting UI for managing users and roles? 
I'm using MVC 4, EF 6.0.1 amd can use the most advanced components. (No limiting legacy :-) ) 
Any leads will highly appreciate. 
Thanks in advance!
Yaron.

Comment: The default MVC4 Internet Application Project comes with an `AccountController` and accompanying models, but no UI for managing these. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The internet template contains open authentication and authorization solution that are not so relevant in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent similar project (MVC4, intranet, EF CF) I had a STI on the users hierarchy, and the discriminator field (which in fact is the "type" of the entity) was used to manage permissions. I made like 3-4 simple filters (like "AdminFilter", "ManagerFilter") and authorized the actions using those filters. It was really quick.

> I'm looking for the most built-in mechanims the achieve it.

I've looked for something like that, but didn't find it. Well, maybe I didn't look for it that much.

Comment: I know that this an option but I Prefer to make the extra effort to select a "from the box" solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help someone... 
At first I have read this great article:
http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties 
I have used simple membership and role and then used the role name as a key in an entity that extends the role with extra information. 
I didn't use the Authorize filter and created custom filter that implements "Feature based authorization". 
The main idea is that the authorization meachnism is a set of features. 
A feature is an activity that some roles can perform while others can't. 
This is a much better architecture that is easier to manage mentain and extend.